# errors while installing mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I want to run django application on centos 8, while installing the dependencies through requirements.txt, I keep getting the error that I believe its coming from mysqlclient==1.3.12. I tried to edit the version 1.3.13 same result. this is the actual error message.      Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-9x7ed00h/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-9x7ed00h/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get
_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-9x7ed00h/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mys
ql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9x
7ed00h/mysqlclient/
(afol) [vagrant@localhost ScrumMaster]$
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqlclient` package depends on a C system library, so I would suggest running the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip3 install mysqlclient
```